# AWS EKS nodes claiming an absurd amount of IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, aws-eks

I run an AWS EKS cluster (v1.24) with a couple c5a.xlarge worker nodes and VPCCNI networking, with ENI trunking enabled and `ENABLE_POD_ENI` set to true in the VPCCNI configuration (some of the pods need specific security groups, hence the need for assigning native ENIs).

Now, the problem is that the subnet that the nodes are in is rapidly running out of IP addresses - each node, even when it has only the `aws-node`, `ebs-csi-node`/`efs-csi-node` and `kube-proxy` pod running, has three ENIs active: the primary interface with 28 IPs, one named `aws-k8s-trunk-eni` with one IP (probably the trunk controller?, and a third one named `aws-K8S-i-xxxxxxxxx` with again 28 IPs.

I have not enabled `ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION`, and the IPs also don't look contiguous - what causes this absurd waste?